# Upgrade to MAMP 4 - can't see app when opening

Tags: installation, upgrade, mamp, mamp-pro

I've had similar issue before but usually ends up popping up. I recently upgraded to MAMP Pro 4 and any time I open app the main window doesn't appear. The application appears to be open, but can't see it. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: I have the same problem, is there a solution already? Holger's answer is not helping me

Comment: Ya, that solution didn't work for me either. I ended up creating a folder in Applications called "Archive" and put all the MAMP folders in there (so I had a backup). I also renamed the ~/Library/Application Support/appsolute folder so I had a backup of that too. I ran installer, restarted machine and it worked for me. Think there was an issue with some legacy files.

Comment: Hi, please contact our support: https://appsolute.zendesk.com/anonymous_requests/new  If the solution with my.cnf file does not work, we need more info from you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into Applications/MAMP PRO and run MAMP PRO Uninstaller
2. Download MAMP_MAMP_PRO_3.5.2 and run it then quit MAMP PRO
3. Download MAMP_MAMP_PRO_4.5 and run it
   Than should fix all the issues

Answer (score 0):

First quit MAMP PRO.

Go to your

~/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/templates/

folder.

Rename your my.cnf.temp file. Restart MAMP PRO.

You will then need to remake any changes you had previously made for your my.cnf template via the File > Edit Template > MySQL when you open MAMP PRO again

See also https://appsolute.zendesk.com/home  first Article.